# Where can I buy custom cut wood sections for my project?

Tags: wood, wood-selection, cutting

I'm working on bathroom vanity unit project. I don’t have any advanced cutting tools, so getting the pieces cut would be a great help. I am thinking of using Ash, are there any other woods/materials that could lend themselves well for this project?

Answer (score 1):

Ash would be a fine material for it, as well as a large number of others.  I would recommend trying to find something like a MakerSpace near you.  They have equipment for all kinds of projects, and all kinds of saws are generally available, not to mention, people to teach you how to use the equipment if you are unsure.

Answer (score 0):

I own a lumber yard over here in Belgium and we're used to also cut and plane (very) small orders for our customers. So you probably should ask at your local supplier if they can do it for you?